# Finding closest element with Manhattan distance not efficient

Tags: python, coordinates, distance

I have a maze with obstacles which has different "power-ups" located on the map. They are just goal destinations which need to be reached eventually. However, the order in which they are reached matters, since we want to be time-efficient.

Let's simulate the following situation:

```
   0  1  2  3
0 [ ][X][ ][ ]
1 [ ][▣][▣][ ]
2 [ ][P][ ][ ]
3 [ ][▣][Y][▣]
4 [ ][▣][ ][ ]

[▣] is an obstacle.
[X] with position (0,1) is a power-up
[Y] with position (3,2) is a power-up
[P] with position (2,1) is the player. In other words, the starting position
```

`[P]` needs to reach a power-up.

In order to decide which one, currently, I am using Manhattan distance to find the closest item:

```
abs(a1[0] - a2[0]) + abs(a1[1] - a2[1])
```

Manhattan distance will calculate that the distance between the `[P]` and `[X]` is 2 and the distance between `[P]` and `[Y]` is also 2. So it will randomly pick one to visit next.

However, Manhattan distance will not take into consideration that there is an obstacle between `[P]` and `[X]` and thus the actual distance will be longer.

So, it will take four steps to reach `[X]`:

```
(2,1) first step-> (2,0) second step-> (1,0) third-> (0,0) fourth-> (0,1)
```

While reaching `[Y]`, will just take 2 steps:

```
(2,1) first step-> (2,2) second step-> (3,2)
```

Since Manhattan distance will in some cases do the job for me, it will not be the most time-efficient method. Additionally, time is key for me since I want to reach all the power-ups in the shortest time possible in order to win the game.

Can someone suggest me how can I optimise this or what other method should I use to compute the closest item with also taking into consideration the obstacles I have?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Dijkstra is natural. You could also look into [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know which power-up is actually the closest you would need to compute actual distances (with obstacles taken into account) for each power-up. After having these distances you could compare them and see which one is actually the closest. 
However, this does't seem to be the optimal solution to you problem since you'd have to do all of the computation in order to make a move.

What you are doing now is quite good, but there is a way we can improve it. You can use this method to determine the Manhattan distance and number of obstacles on it:

```
def manhattan_d_obstacles(grid, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    obs_count = 0
    if x1 > x2:
        x_range = range(x2, x1)
    else:
        x_range = range(x1, x2)
    if y1 > y2:
        y_range = range(y1, y2)
    else:
        y_range = range(y2, y1)
    for i in x_range:
        for j in y_range:
            if grid[i, j] == 'obstacle':
                obs_counter += 1
    return {
        "dist": abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2),
        "obs": obs_counter
    }
```

Now you can simply use this method to compare Manhattan distances and number of obstacles on that path. So:

```
best = {
    "dist": float("inf"), # int("inf") does not exist
    "obs": float("inf") # int("inf") does not exist
}
for pwu in power_ups:
    path = manhattan_d_obstacles(P['x'], P['y'], pwu['x'], pwu['y'])
    if path['dist'] < best['dist']:
        best = path
    elif path['dist'] == best['dist'] and path['obs'] < best['obs']:
        best = path
```

This function generally runs faster than computing the actual distance in case that the actual route is different than the Manhattan route (i.e. what P -> Y is in your example). Otherwise, it runs the same speed.